# Regex match start of string inside lookahead

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match just the word Hello on the first and third lines:

```
     Hello should be matched
I do not want this Hello to be matched
Hello should be matched
```

When I use `^\s*Hello`, things almost work but I do not want the spaces to actually be included in the result.

`(?=\s*)Hello` is closer but matches all 3 Hellos.

I would expected either `^(?=\s*)Hello` or `(?=^\s*)Hello` to work, and am confused as to why they don't. Why don't these work and how can I create a regex that matches *only* the "Hello" after some whitespace?

Comment: `Lookbehind` doesn't work in Javascript.

Comment: Sorry I should clarify - I'm trying to make a complex search in atom.io, which does not use capture groups.

Comment: What do you want to do after match ?

Comment: The input you have given always have `Hello` preceded by at least one space. Which means the word **Hello** will always have one space before and after it. Which brings me to match literal word which can be done by `/Hello/`, but I guess that's not what you need.

Comment: If you want to match something before the string, you have to use lookbehind, not lookahead. But JS doesn't have lookbehind.

Comment: @Barmar That's too bad; thank you. If you post that answer I'll accept it if someone doesn't come up with a workaround.

Comment: @DanielCentore It's not an answer, it's a non-answer. If you search for "javascript lookbehind workaround" you'll find them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to specify where the match came from (first line, third line, etc.). The only way to do this properly is to input the sentences, line by line, and programatically keep track of which line the match came from.

This regex will match what you are looking for

```
\b([H|h]ello)\b
```

What you need to do is wrap what you are looking for in ( ) which act as the capture goup

Edited -

```
^\s*(Hello)
```

Comment: I don't think he wants to match a specific line number. He wants to match the word any time it's at the beginning of a line, with optional spaces before it.

Comment: Ahhhh, I read it that he wanted to read the first and third lines ... Now I see he just wanted to match the "hello" in the first and third... Just edited.

Answer (score 0):

Create a capture group:

```js
str1 = '     Hello should be matched';
str2 = 'I do not want this Hello to be matched';
str3 = 'Hello should be matched';

str1 = str1.match(/^\s*(Hello)/);
if (str1) {
  str1 = str1[1];
} else {
  str1 = '';
}
str2 = str2.match(/^\s*(Hello)/);
if (str2) {
  str2 = str2[1];
} else {
  str2 = '';
}
str3 = str3.match(/^\s*(Hello)/);
if (str3) {
  str3 = str3[1];
} else {
  str3 = '';
}
$('#output').append('str1: ' + str1 + '<br>str2: ' + str2 + '<br>str3: ' + str3 + '');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution for you:

```
^\b(Hello)\b.*\n.*\n\b(Hello)\b.*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/vZ9pF8/1